# TagInput Tag Input - Mutli line input field

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, input, blueprintjs

I will happily accept guidance/pointers/ideas if you don't have a complete response.

I am currently working on updating an Email system built using React and elements of Blueprint JS.

In the email dialog, I am attempting to move the `To` and `CC` fields from being a text input to a TagInput system using BlueprintJS/labs' TagInput.

http://blueprintjs.com/docs/v1/#labs/tag-input

You will see in the example contained in the link above, that their TagInput field will allow you to add new Tags to the input field. Once the length of those tags exceeds the width of the input field, it will add a new line to the input field and allow you to continue adding tags.

From my knowledge, input fields do not normally allow for multiple lines.

How can this be achieved? In my code currently, once the tags exceed the width of the input field, it will continue to add new tags on a new line below the input, however, it will not increase the height of the input field to compensate. (Giving the appearance of tags floating magically outside of the input, hovering over & obstructing other content.)

The image below shows the effect. (The CC field is the TagInput - as you can see, the tags below the first line just 'hover in space' and cover the subject field, and eventually move down to cover the email body.)

[image]

The TagInput is simply defined..

```
<TagInput
    className='pt-fill pt-input-ghost'
    onChange={(cc: string[]) => this.setState({cc})}
    values={this.state.cc}
    inputValue={this.state.cc_input}
    placeholder='CC:'
    leftIconName='document-share'
/>
```

Also, I have a little bit of modified CSS

```
.pt-input{
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.pt-tag-input{
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.pt-tag {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
}

.pt-tag-input-icon{
    margin-right: 2px;
}

.pt-input-ghost{
    border:none;
    outline-style:none;
    outline:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    border-color:transparent;
    margin: 2px 0px;
    background-color:transparent;
}

.pt-input-ghost:focus{
    border:none;
    outline-style:none;
    outline:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    border-color:transparent;
    background-color:transparent;
    width: auto;
}
```

Thanks for all the help :)

Again, I will happily accept guidance/pointers/ideas if you don't have a complete response.

Comment: Thank you @Sphinx for the edit - My reputation would not allow me to do so

Answer (score 0):

A few notes about the TagInput implementation: it's not actually an `<input>` element, just styled to look like one! The component is actually a div full of tags with an `<input>` at the end for you to type into.

The default styles of the component allow its height to grow to fit the content, which may wrap to multiple lines.

Your screenshot suggests that your app has some styles (not quoted above) that prevent the `TagInput` from growing as it should, so the tags spill out and cover the content below.

Comment: Thanks for reading through the questions here. I found that if I inspect the TagInput div with Chrome developer tools ( class='pt-input pt-tag-input pt-input-ghost' ), and navigate to the 'pt-input' class and disable the 'height: 30px;' property, it works as intended. I find this strange because it looks like 'height: 30px;' is the blueprint standard. 

I still have not been able to solve this so it loads properly.